# What's wrong with my backpropagation through time (BTT) calculation or how to multiple a scaled vector and a matrix without matching dimensions?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, rnn, linear-algebra

I am trying to make a pretty simple RNN from scracth, using only Numpy library of Python. 
At this moment I am having troubles with BTT as I do not know how to proceed with situation when a multiplication of a scaled vector and a matrix, without matching dimensions, should be made. 
Probably, I made a mistake somewhere and this situation is just a consequce of it. However, I was not able to identify any.

For the presentation purposes I have written my calculation on a piece of paper. Here's the screenshot of it->>>[Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69O5u.jpg)

So, could anyone please point to the mistake I made. Or if there is not any error, then how should I proceed? How to muplitply vectors/matrices when they do not have matching dimensions?
I know there is a technique called padding, when '1's are added to match dimensions but I am not sure it is relevant here.

Anyway, thanks for the reading and your answers!

**UPDATE:** I figured out my mistake. I need to multiply 1 by 4 vector with 1 by 5 vector, not 3 by 5 matrix as it is matrix with all inputs of this particulat training example. Here I need only X3 to calculate how change in Wx affect H3. Outer product will produce a matrix with exact dimensions required - 5 by 4 matrix